# MapperParsingException on doing rebuild_index in django-haystack with elasticsearch

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using `java 1.7.0_95`, `Django 1.8.4`, `Python 3.4.0`, `Django Rest Framework 3.1.3`, `ElasticSearch 2.3.1`, `pyelasticsearch 1.4` and `Django Haystack 2.4.1`

I'm experiencing an error in elasticsearch every time I try to do `python manage.py rebuild_index`. This is the error:

```
MapperParsingException[Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_boost : {null_value=1.0, name=boost}]]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.checkNoRemainingFields(DocumentMapperParser.java:171)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:159)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:99)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:498)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$PutMappingExecutor.applyRequest(MetaDataMappingService.java:257)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$PutMappingExecutor.execute(MetaDataMappingService.java:230)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService.runTasksForExecutor(InternalClusterService.java:468)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:772)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:231)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:194)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my configuration:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}

HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'

HAYSTACK_SEARCH_RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 40
```

Comment: There is no `ElasticSearch 1.9.0`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @AndreiStefan , I just corrected it to 2.3.1 in my question. Must have mixed it up with something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a relevant `django-haystack` issue to remove the `boost` parameter which is no longer supported in `ElasticSearch` >= 2:

- [Remove boost which is now unsupported](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/pull/1313)

Before that change, `django-haystack` was using the `_boost` parameter in the mapping for the `ElasticSearch` backend. The change was made to the master branch. You can do things at this moment:

- install the development version of `django-haystack` directly from github:

  ```
  pip install -e git+https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack.git@master#egg=django-haystack
  ```
- downgrade `ElasticSearch` to the latest stable version before the upgrade to the 2nd, I think it is [`1.7.3`](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-1-7-3)

Also, here is the relevant discussion:

- [Django haystack LocationField created as string instead of geo_point in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443179/django-haystack-locationfield-created-as-string-instead-of-geo-point-in-elastics)

Comment: Thanks @alecxe, that worked! Appreciate your help :-)